# Retrieve hostnames for IP addresses to connect to HTTP services, when no (reverse) DNS PTR records are available?

Tags: http, webserver, ip, reconnaissance

I'm conducting a penetration test, where I'm facing the following problem:

After having retrieved a set of IP addresses through tools like `whois`, I cannot successfully connect to the HTTP-based websites/services using the IP address, only the hostname work. However, no DNS PTR records exists for the IP addresses.

Using `nc` or similar to connect directly to the website/service using the IP address doesn't work - it expects HTTP requests only. Furhermore, DNS zone transfer doesn't work.

This reason is that the webserver/firewall inspects the HTTP `Host` header and responds with a `HTTP 404`, if the `Host` header contains an IP address.  It may do so because of virtual hosting, or maybe the request is being filtered as a security precaution.

In this case, how can I connect to the web servers under these restrictions?

Comment: How were you able to start the investigation with `whois` without knowing something about the domains?

Comment: Have you tried tools that enumerate domains on IPs, like: https://dnslytics.com/ip/185.26.149.10

Comment: Have you seen things like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621682/reverse-ip-find-domain-names-on-ip-address

Comment: Are we assuming that this is a normal public website? If so, then there must be DNS records so that people can connect.

Comment: @schroeder - I know a few hostnames; using these, I've identified several blocks of IP adresses.

Comment: @schroeder - very interesting. I tried your dnslytics.com and it found the hostname using the Whois+ tool. Do you know why Whois+ can find it, when no DNS PTR is defined? Do you know how to use Whois+ from the command-line? It would be easier than using a website. The ordinary `whois` Linux program could not find this information.

Comment: try the next suggestion ...

Comment: @schroeder - Thank you. I understand how a database of hostname to IP address mappings is built, but I still cannot find the service that I want. host.io requires the hostname (not the IP address), and I cannot find the "Whois+" tool mentioned on dnslytics.com - the Whois+ tool provides the hostname for the IP address. Do you know of the Whois+ tool?